# i want to replace the text with quotes in a string with a special character and push the values in to array replaced in to a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
input : note_description = 'test @8:57am', patient_id = '009876', note_updated_by = '1009876549087', note_update_date = '2022-07-13 09:45:49' where note_id = '639'

output1 : note_description = ?, patient_id = ?, note_updated_by = ? , note_update_date = ? where note_id = ?

output2 : ['test @8:57am' , '009876' ,'1009876549087' , '2022-07-13 09:45:49' , '639' ]
```

i want to replace the text with quotes in a string with a special character and push the values in to array replaced in to a array

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **RegEx** to solve the problem.

```
function replaceAndGetValuesInQuotes(str) {
    let re = /'([^']+)'/g, text;
    let results = { 
       output1: str.replaceAll(re, '?'),
       output2: []
    };
    while(text = re.exec(str)) {
       results.output2.push(text[1]);
    }
    return results;
}
replaceAndGetValuesInQuotes("note_description = 'test @8:57am', patient_id = '009876', note_updated_by = '1009876549087', note_update_date = '2022-07-13 09:45:49' where note_id = '639'");
```